# VS Code: Connect to code server within docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Hi probably it feels odd to you, but for a project I need to setup VS Code Server in a docker container to setup a DevVM-like solution, although I know docker is not intended to be used like this.

To do so, I basically use this docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server

After starting the container I can access the containerized VS Code via the browser. But my team would prefer to access it directly with their locally installed VS Code.

Usually you can do so via the Remote Tunnel feature, that will create a tunnel through https://vscode.dev/tunnel/.

We would rather like not to do this for security reasons. That's why I am wondering if there are any solutions to connect directly to the VS Code Server from VS Code without the need to tunnel the connection over the internet, e.g. by giving VS Code the IP and port to the dockerized VS Code Server.

Thanks a lot for all input in advance!